# Convert string of numbers into 'binary representation'

Tags: performance, go, bitmask

Im recently made the "Winning Lottery Ticket" coding challange on hackerrank.
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/winning-lottery-ticket/

The idea is to count the combinations of two lines which contain all numbers from 0-9, in the example below its 5 combinations in total.

```
56789
129300455 
5559948277
012334556 
123456879
```

The idea is to change the the representation of something quicker for checking if all numbers are contained.
Example representation:
1278 --> 01100001100

Example with using the first two lines from above:
56789129300455 --> 1111111111

When checking if a number is contained with the concatenation of 2 lines I can abort directly if I encounter a zero because thats not gonna be a pair with all 0-9.

This logic works, but it fails when having a huge amount of lines to compare.

```
// Go code 
func winningLotteryTicket(tickets []string) int {

    counter := 0
    for i := 0; i < len(tickets); i++ {
        for j := i + 1; j < len(tickets); j++ {
            
            if err := bitMask(fmt.Sprintf("%v%v", tickets[i], tickets[j])); err == nil {
                counter++
             }

        }
    }
 

    return counter
}

func bitMask(s string) error {

    for i := 0; i <= 9; i++ {
        if !strings.Contains(s, strconv.Itoa(i)) {
            return errors.New("No Pair")
        } 
    }

    return nil
}
```

Not sure if this representation is called a bitMaks, if not please correct me and I will adjust this post.

From my point of view there is no way the improove performance on the concatenation of the strings because I will have to check each combination.

For checking if a number is contained within the string at the function "bitMask" im not sure.
Do you have an idea how this could perform better ?

Comment: It's definitely not a bitmask, and you're not doing a binary representation anywhere. I would approach this with an actual binary bitmask for each line, and use a bitwise `&` to get the combined value for a pair of lines, and if it does not equal `0b1111111111` then it doesn't contain all digits.

Comment: Bit masks are integers, not strings of ones and zeros. It's called a bitmask because you're not interested in the numerical value of these integers but only in the bit pattern. You can use [bitwise operations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators) on integers and those are really fast because they are implemented in hardware, directly in the CPU. Adrian's suggestion is good, except it's a bitwise OR to combine two lines, not an AND.

Comment: @Adrian Could you please give me a code example for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Bit masks are integers, not strings of ones and zeros. It's called a bitmask because we're not interested in the numerical value of these integers but only in the bit pattern. We can use bitwise operations on integers and those are really fast because they are implemented in hardware, directly in the CPU.

Here is a function that turns a string into an actual bitmask, with each one-bit signaling that a particular digit is present in the string:

```golang
func mask(s string) uint16 {
    // We need ten bits, one for each possible decimal digit in s, so int16 and
    // uint16 are the smallest possible integer types that fit. For bitmasks it
    // is typical to select an unsigned type because the sign bit doesn't have
    // any meaning. As I said earlier, mask's numerical value is irrelevant.
    var mask uint16

    for _, c := range s {
        switch c {
        case '0':
            mask |= 0b0000000001
        case '1':
            mask |= 0b0000000010
        case '2':
            mask |= 0b0000000100
        case '3':
            mask |= 0b0000001000
        case '4':
            mask |= 0b0000010000
        case '5':
            mask |= 0b0000100000
        case '6':
            mask |= 0b0001000000
        case '7':
            mask |= 0b0010000000
        case '8':
            mask |= 0b0100000000
        case '9':
            mask |= 0b1000000000
        }
    }

    return mask
}
```

This is rather verbose, but it should be pretty obvious what happens.

Note that the binary number literals can be replaced with bit shifts:

- `0b0000000001` is the same as `1<<0` (1 shifted zero times to the left)
- `0b0000000010` is the same as `1<<1` (1 shifted one time to the left
- `0b0000000100` is the same as `1<<2` (1 shifted two times to the left), and so on

Using this, and taking advantage of the fact that the bytes '0' through '9' are themselves just integers (48 through 57 in decimal, given by their place in the [ASCII table](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html), we can shorten this function like so:

```
func mask(s string) uint16 { 
    var mask uint16

    for _, c := range s {
        if '0' <= c && c <= '9' {
            mask |= 1 << (c - '0')
        }
    }

    return mask
}
```

To check two lines, then, all we have to do is OR the masks for the lines and compare to `0b1111111111` (i.e. check if all ten bits are set):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := "56789"
    b := "129300455"

    mA := mask(a)
    mB := mask(b)

    fmt.Printf("mask(%11q) = %010b\n", a, mA)
    fmt.Printf("mask(%11q) = %010b\n", b, mB)
    fmt.Printf("combined          = %010b\n", mA|mB)
    fmt.Printf("all digits present: %v\n", mA|mB == 0b1111111111)
}

func mask(s string) uint16 {
    var mask uint16
    
    for _, c := range s {
        if '0' <= c && c <= '9' {
            mask |= 1 << (c - '0')
        }
    }

    return mask
}
```

```
mask(    "56789") = 1111100000
mask("129300455") = 1000111111
combined          = 1111111111
all digits present: true
```

Try it on the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/mr1KqnC9phB

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So far I understand everything except the substraction of zero on the value of c **mask |= 1 << (c - '0')**. What does this do?

Comment: `'0'` is a byte literal, and bytes are just integers. `c - '0'` can also be written as `c - 48`. It simply computes the offset of c from '0', which exactly the position of the bit representing c. It really is just a compact way of computing the binary literal in the first version. https://play.golang.org/p/Q3X2UUeofFh

Comment: Good to know this. Just to sum this up for easier understanding. The decimal ASCII representation of "0-9" is "48-57" which means that by substracting 'c' wich will be sth. in between 48-57 with 48 we result in 0-9 which is exaclty what we need for the mask.